# Select rows in pandas matching time condition

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I have a csv with data like this:

```
[id  names          timestamp                   is_valid]
[1   name:surname   2016-06-09 23:29:50.083093      True]
```

I need to select rows based on this condition: if is_valid is true and if timestamp has passed 24 hours. So it should be **True** and current time **2016-06-10 23:29:50.083093** to pass the condition.

How can I achieve this? I know how to apply the first condition:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser

df=pd.read_csv('acc.csv') 
user=(df[df['is_valid']==True])
```

I can even print timestamp, parse it and compare with datetime.now(). But this is definitely a terrible thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser

df = pd.read_csv('acc.csv')
tidx = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].values)
past_24 = (pd.datetime.now() - tidx).total_seconds() > 60 * 60 * 24
user = df[df['is_valid'] & past_24]
```

Comment: yup, it does the trick! (at first I had no results, but then realized 24hrs haven't passed yet -_- ) Thanks!